# storing different file types than images as base64

Tags: base64

I know that it is possible to store image files as base64 encoded strings, now I wonder if it would also be possible to store a different file format in base64 as well, in my case it would be 3D File (.dae/Collada)

Answer (score 0):

You can effectively store any kind of binary file with a base64. Please note that it might take a significant space. The following example takes 100 random bytes and convert them to base64:

```sh
$ head -c100 /dev/urandom | base64
TCOMGPuMB5PHUnnPWctxzlox4tLH/zgVQ4S+3PDHfZN7v+dwjs2aKQRr9uNdBtQqUpk9ZZfVM3da
FFxza+hul8s64UXVt8OAsSfTwDmyO1bvI+CzrGm6hGdqUvIqD6pziGln8A==
```